# How to send automatic email/s to the approve/s of content on my enterprise wiki

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, wiki, content-approval

I have created a publishing site which contain enterprise wiki and for some sites I define that I contents require approval before being published. Currently the new wiki article will not be published unless a user with an “Approve” permission goes and approve it. But I need to know if there is a way so that SharePoint can automatically send an email to all the users which have “Approve permission” so that they know that there is a wiki article which is waiting their approvals.

Best Regards

Comment: Would you not add a workflow to the list to make this happen?

Answer (score 3):

You can use workflows to accomplish this. Turn on Content approval, then create a workflow that has the email and approval elements you require. Here are some resources to help you along:

Get started with workflows in SharePoint 2013
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163917.aspx

SharePoint 2013 workflow fundamentals
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163181.aspx

Creating an Approval Workflow for SharePoint 2013
http://blog.incworx.com/blog/who-is-the-best-chicago-sharepoint-firm/creating-an-approval-workflow-for-sharepoint-2013

All about Approval workflows
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/all-about-approval-workflows-HA102771433.aspx